How to find what port is connected to serial cable on MacBook?
I am trying to control a few NEAT-310 modules using python from my macbook. The modules use a serial rs-232 25 pin cable, and I'm connecting to them with a serial to usb cable. The modules themselves control motors that move a mount, and instead of pressing the buttons on the modules themselves I want to be able to use python to tell the module "move the motor to this position".
The code I wrote is as follows:
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB4', # Update with the correct serial port
    baudrate=9600,       # NEAT 310 uses 9600 baud rate 
    bytesize=8,      # 8 data bits
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, # No parity
    stopbits=1,          # 1 stop bit
    timeout=10            # Adjust timeout as needed
)

# Send "VI" command to set initial velocity
cmd = "VI5\r\n"  # Don't forget to terminate commands with \r\n
ser.write(cmd.encode()) #what did this do again?

# Read response if any
response = ser.readline()

ser.close #Always close the port

My problem is the port= line. I'm not sure what port to find. In my terminal, I tried
ls /dev/tty.*

before and after plugging the cable in, but nothing new appears on the list.

/dev/tty.* should be /dev/tty*. There's no . in the filename.

And perhaps use /dev/ttyUSB* so you only see USB serial ports.

@Barmar it says /dev/ttyUSB* is not found. Also, /dev/tty* gives a list of many tty ports and I'm not even sure how to read the list it gives.

If nothing is found, I don't see how ttyUSB4 was working when you were hard-coding it.

Oh, it wasn't; I was running through different USB* values to see if something would work as I saw it on a different post.

https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J36/5.b

I've seen that link as well. I tried it, but I still get no matches found in my terminal.

One way to find the device special file is to list all devices before attaching ls -l /dev > /tmp/a then plug in your device and do ls -l /dev > /tmp/b. Then run opendiff /tmp/[ab]

Using ls /dev/tty* gives the list I mentioned earlier. Items are listed as /dev/tty*., where * is some letter (like p, q, s, etc.) and . is some number in sequential order (so it's like /dev/ttys1, /dev/ttys2,..., /dev/ttysa,...).
